# Facebook Graph Api Insights metrics does not show

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I use the Graph API to get the facebooks insights data, for some reason for December 6 and 7 in none of my pages I get the "metric" Friends of fans it doesnt even give me a 0 it is just not there.

There are a couple that also dissapeared like engaged users.

those metrics do not have the deprecated sign in the list, also those metrics are pretty new with the API changes.

Does anyone know of a reason why a metric would not appear? speacially friends of fans.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having this issue right now, did you ever find a reason or a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem from Facebook graph API.Some other metric values are also missing.
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/463636353736155/